# Insert values from A table to A table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table in mysql that stores menu items. Structure is as below

Table: `menu_list_hed`

```
id    menu_name    shop_id    menu category
--------------------------------------------
 1     Breakfast      12          Veg
 2     Dinner         12          Veg
 .... Many more
```

Now, i have another shop which has same menu but `shop_id`(13) is different. How can i copy same values again and make table look like as below

```
id    menu_name    shop_id    menu category
--------------------------------------------
 1     Breakfast      12          Veg
 2     Dinner         12          Veg
 .... Many more
 25    Breakfast      13          Veg
 26    Dinner         13          Veg
 .... Many more
```

I tried exporting SQL from phpmyadmin but that will take lots of time as i have to manually change the `shop_id` for each SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use insert with select and provide your shop_id in select statement

```
INSERT INTO menu_list_hed
    (`menu_name`, `shop_id`, `menu category`)
select `menu_name`, '13' AS `shop_id`, `menu category`
from menu_list_hed where shop_id = 12
;
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba2ca/1)

Comment: this query says that `Mysql Returned 0 set`

Comment: @GagandeepSharma you have this [*Fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba2ca/1) which is working also how you are trying this query can you also create a sample fiddle with your  sample data and query ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid .. i created fiddle `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b34ce/11 and it is working fne but it is gving empty resultset in mysql PhpMyadmin Database

Comment: `shop_id` here is foreign key of main `shop` table

Comment: Now.. i have another table .. in which `menu_items` needs to be inserted against each `menu_category` ... how can i achieve this.. or i am writing new question instead

Comment: @GagandeepSharma i guess its new question so ask another one :)

Comment: @m Khalid Junaid ... new question is here [Go to New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094179/insert-values-from-two-tables-into-one-table)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, have a sub query of to the same table to match the shop_id. Hope at least this structure helps you

> **INSERT** **INTO** shop(id , menu_name, shop_id, 'menu category')
>
> **SELECT** MAX(id) + 1 , menu_name ,
> (**SELECT** MAX((shop_id)) +1 **FROM** menu_list_hed h1
> where h1.menu_name = h2.menu_name), `menu category`)
> **FROM**
> menu_list_hed h2;

Answer (score 1):

Write query like this

```
INSERT INTO destination_table ( 
      Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3) 
SELECT Field_1, 
      Field_2, 
      Field_3 
      FROM source_table;
```

Comment: this way i have to write very long query then,,