# Insert values from two tables into one table

Tags: mysql

Now, new scenario in continuation to [Base Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092997/insert-values-from-a-table-to-a-table) is as below:

Table:`menu_list_hed`

```
menu_id    menu_name    shop_id    menu category
--------------------------------------------
 1        Breakfast      12          Veg
 2        Dinner         12          Veg
 .... Many more
 85       Breakfast      13          Veg
 36       Dinner         13          Veg
 .... Many more
```

I have another table called `menu_items` which already has items for `shop_id` 12

```
id     shop_id    menu_id   item_name
--------------------------------------
 1      12           1       Roti
 2      12           1       Prantha
 3      12           2       Thali
 4      12           2       Sweet
 .... many More
```

Now i want the items to be inserted for `shop_id` 13 because `items` are same but `shop_id` and `menu_id` will be different as below:

```
  id     shop_id    menu_id   item_name
--------------------------------------
 1      12           1       Roti
 2      12           1       Prantha
 3      12           2       Thali
 4      12           2       Sweet
 .... many More
 111     13          85      Roti
 112     13          85      Prantha
 113     13          36      Thali
 114     13          36      Sweet
```

i copied values by using query in previous question and then running update statement like as

```
UPDATE item  SET `menu_id`= 85 where `menu_id` = 1 and restaurant_id = 13;
```

but i want to achieve it with single query

Comment: What do I get paid to write your code?

Comment: a heartfull of thanks :)  ..  not sure why -2 :(

Comment: I guess that is because you are basicly asking "I want this, what is the code"

Comment: no... @Azrael .. u got it wrong.. please upvote it as  i m looking for better way

Comment: @GagandeepSharma see *Strawberry*'s answer

Comment: One more upvote please as we are here to find best alternate wayout

Comment: @GagandeepSharma for your current problem it can be easily handled at your application level code like with php,asp ... in one query this can be v hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO menu_items (shop_id, menu_id, item_name) 
SELECT 13,  menu_id + 24,  item_name FROM  menu_items
```

Comment: but `menu_id` does not have exact increments.. it can be any ID ..edited my question please see now

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to use 2 queries:

You could have made the menu_id col as identity column else you can do a max

```
INSERT INTO menu_list_hed
    (`menu_id`,menu_name`, `shop_id`, `menu category`)
select max(menu_id)+1 `menu_name`, '13' AS `shop_id`, `menu category`
from menu_list_hed where shop_id = 12
;
```

Unless you want to add some specific id's and it's just something you want for uniqueness, it should do.